# TeX distribution with program signature from distributer?

Tags: distributions

Different to pretty all of my colleagues I still want to use LaTeX at work once in a while. In the past I simply used a portable installation to circumvent the fact that I would need administrator access in order to install programs.

Now my employer updated to Windows 10 and increased the security level in a way that only such programs can be executed that a) have a signature which is b) registered on a white list. In principle my employer would allow me to install officially LaTeX. I have already TeXstudio running. Up to now it is worthless, however, as the MiKTeX behind I have so far is not following the two mentioned conditions.

Has anyone an idea if there is a version of MiKTeX or TeXLive that comes with the demanded signature? Registering each single executable seems not to be an option following my tech guys here due to network performance reasons.

Thank you for your help!